# Returning the top 3 values in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using these 3 formulas to return the #1, #2 and #3 top referral source, in other words the value that appears the most times, 2nd most times and 3rd most times. It has been working perfectly until I today when the #2 and #3 happened to appear the same number of times. The result is that the #2 and #3 result are returning the same name.

Any ideas on how I can fix this or perhaps a different way of returning the top 3 occurring values in a range?

## 1 Most occurring Referral Source

=INDEX(T:T, 10000*MOD(MAX(COUNTIF(T11:T992,T11:T992)+(ROW(T11:T992)/10000)),1), 1)

## 2nd most occurring Referral Source

=INDEX(T11:T992,MODE(IF((T11:T992<>"")*(T11:T992<>INDEX(T11:T992,MODE(IF(T11:T992<>"",MATCH(T11:T992,T11:T992,0))))),MATCH(T11:T992,T11:T992,0))))

## 3 most occurring Referral Source

=INDEX(T11:T992,MODE(IF(((T11:T992<>"")*(T11:T992<>INDEX(T11:T992,MODE(IF(T11:T992<>"",MATCH(T11:T992,T11:T992,0)))))*(T11:T992<>INDEX(T11:T992,MODE(IF((T11:T992<>"")*(T11:T992<>INDEX(T11:T992,MODE(IF(T11:T992<>"",MATCH(T11:T992,T11:T992,0))))),MATCH(T11:T992,T11:T992,0)))))),MATCH(T11:T992,T11:T992,0))))

Comment: An example of the data would go a long way to helping, but I would look at the large() function as a first step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data is just a column with names. The large function uses numeric values, my data is text so large wouldn’t work, at least I don’t think it would.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a working formula from another excel forum that worked perfectly:

jasonb75 said:
Try this for all 3 note that there are 2 instances of D$1:D1 in the formula which need to be changed, these should refer to the cell directly above the first formula before dragging down, e.g. if the formula is going into D2, then it would be D$1:D1, if it is going into Z10 then it would be Z$9:Z9

=INDEX(T:T,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($T$11:$T$992)/(COUNTIF($T$11:$T$992,$T$11:$T$992)=AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIF($T$11:$T$992,$T$11:$T$992),1+SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($T$11:$T$992,D$1:D1))))/ISNA(MATCH($T$11:$T$992,D$1:D1,0)),1))